# Where's my tank?

Tags: grand-theft-auto-v

I bought a Rhino Tank from Warstock Cache & Carry, as Franklin. I expected the tank to be delivered to the Grove Street Garage, but it's not there. Where should I be looking to find it? If it's not delivered to the purchasing character's garage, then where? Is the location different for each character?